# Creating a variable that uses vertical lookup in another variable

Tags: stata

How could you create a variable that would indicate presence or non-presence (0/1) of a certain condition by looking through multiple observations in another variable? (Hence this vertical lookup is to be bounded by the time period.)

For example, in the sample code below, a new variable `tag_prodcateg1` should equal to 1 for all categories (1, 2, and 3) only if category 1 was on display in a corresponding week.

> 

```
clear
input str2 product  prodcategory    promo week tag_prodcateg1
A 1 1 1 1
B 1 0 1 1  
C 2 1 1 1
D 2 1 1 1
E 3 0 1 1
F 3 0 1 1
A 1 0 2 0
B 1 0 2 0 
C 2 1 2 0
D 2 1 2 0
E 3 0 2 0
F 3 0 2 0
X 4 1 3 .
Y 4 1 3 .

end
```

I am only able to go as far as doing it for all observations at once (i.e. not on a week-by-week basis):

```
egen uniqueid=group(prodcategory week)
bysort uniqueid: egen sumdisp=total(promo) if prodcategory==1
gen tagsubcatweekondisp=1 if sumdisp>0
replace tagsubcatweekondisp=0 if tagsubcatweekondisp==.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the job.

```
generate pc1p = prodcategory==1 & promo==1
bysort week (product): egen tag1 = max(pc1p)
```

which yields the following results

```
. list, clean noobs

    product   prodca~y   promo   week   tag_pr~1   pc1p   tag1  
          A          1       1      1          1      1      1  
          B          1       0      1          1      0      1  
          C          2       1      1          1      0      1  
          D          2       1      1          1      0      1  
          E          3       0      1          1      0      1  
          F          3       0      1          1      0      1  
          A          1       0      2          0      0      0  
          B          1       0      2          0      0      0  
          C          2       1      2          0      0      0  
          D          2       1      2          0      0      0  
          E          3       0      2          0      0      0  
          F          3       0      2          0      0      0
```

The code above addresses the original problem: create a variable that is 1 for all observations in a given week if one of the observations was for productcategory = 1 and had promo = 1. Now the problem has been updated to include that the variable needs to be 2, rather than 0, if there were  no observations for productcategory = 1 in the given week.

The code above shows general technique for copying a result from one observation to other related observations. To solve the new problem, the same technique will apply. The code below does what I understand is wanted. But the lesson is that the same technique that allowed the solving of the original problem can be understood and used to solve further, essentially identical, problems.

```
generate pc1p = prodcategory==1 & promo==1
bysort week (product): egen tag1 = max(pc1p)
generate pc2 = prodcategory==1
bysort week (product): egen tag2 = max(pc2)
replace tag1 = 2 if tag1==0 & tag2==0
list, clean noobs
```

which yields the following results, with tag1 now taking the value 2 for observations in week 3, when productcategory 1 does not appear.

```
. list, clean noobs

product   prodca~y   promo   week   tag_pr~1   pc1p   tag1   pc2   tag2  
      A          1       1      1          1      1      1     1      1  
      B          1       0      1          1      0      1     1      1  
      C          2       1      1          1      0      1     0      1  
      D          2       1      1          1      0      1     0      1  
      E          3       0      1          1      0      1     0      1  
      F          3       0      1          1      0      1     0      1  
      A          1       0      2          0      0      0     1      1  
      B          1       0      2          0      0      0     1      1  
      C          2       1      2          0      0      0     0      1  
      D          2       1      2          0      0      0     0      1  
      E          3       0      2          0      0      0     0      1  
      F          3       0      2          0      0      0     0      1  
      X          4       1      3          .      0      2     0      0  
      Y          4       1      3          .      0      2     0      0
```

Comment: This condenses to `egen tag1 = max(prodcategory==1 & promo==1), by(week)`.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it tags as 0 even those observations when they are not applicable. For example, if a subcategory never appeared in a week, it would still assign a 0. Hence, it give a wrong impression that it was simply not on display, when in fact it was non-existent. Is it possible to tag such observations as missing or else, in order to give a clear representation of the actual "on promotion/off promotion" situation? (the code above is corrected for that). Newly added X and Y are reflecting my ideal way of encoding.

Comment: Why have non-existent states in your dataset?

Comment: Oh, good question! They represent the "other" category, that I am not concerned about for now, but have to have for a compete picture. I will mark those as "2". So, in total, for each new variable, I will have 0, 1, and 2. (Those observations are needed to be present for cross-interactions among other variables.)

Comment: It's not a problem with William's code that it doesn't do something not in the original question. Just condition your calculation on your values being 0 or 1.

Comment: Or `replace` with missing if the variable concerned is 2.

Comment: William's code works very well, thank you. William, can you please in words explain what does `sort week (newupc): egen tag2 = max(pc2)`do ?

Comment: And how does `bysort week (product): egen tag1 = max(pc1p)` and `bysort week (product): egen tag2 = max(pc2)` change if the data is now has to account for store/week/product differences? (not just week/product)

Comment: I think, it should be `besot week store (product): egen tag1 = max(pc1p)` and `besot week store (product): egen tag2 = max(pc2)`?

Comment: In the most recent comment, you have correctly answered the question you posed in the second most recent comment. In the third most recent comment, I can do no better than advise you to become familiar with the Stata documentation. The output of `help by` and `help egen` will get you started on your question, and you can read the full documentation for `by` and `egen` in the _Stata Data Management Reference Manual_ PDF included with your Stata installation and accessible from Stata's Help menu. Stata supplies exceptionally good documentation that amply repays the time spent studying it.